# Add new line character in string

Tags: android, textview, newline

How to make a new line after every text??

This's the code.

```
String body = txtName.getText().toString() + txtLatitude.getText().toString() + txtLongitude.getText().toString();
ii.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
```

I tried to use only `\n` but it's giving me error. Please help me.

Comment: What's the error in it? `\n` works for new line text.

Comment: please replace + with +"\n"+.

Answer (score 5):

```
String body = txtName.getText().toString() + "\n" + txtLatitude.getText().toString() + "\n" + txtLongitude.getText().toString();
```

Comment: I think it should be perfect.use "\n" for new line but in between + "\n" + .

Answer (score 1):

You can use html tag in your string like this.

```
String body = Html.fromHtml(txtName.getText().toString()+"<br />"
                    + txtLatitude.getText().toString()+"<br />"
                    + txtLongitude.getText().toString()+"<br />");
```

Answer (score 0):

I take it you are using android java. Unsure, but in c++ you can use the endl function in std library. I think there is a similar function, system.getproperty("line.separator") or ("line.new") you could try it, It is something close to this. Also Since "\n" doesn't work, try single quotes '\n' it is a newline character so it might count as a single character in java. Other than that 
 can also work it is standard HTML.

Comment: aka   string =  blah + System.getProperty("line.seperator") + blah;